# Reorder Multiindex Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I would like to reorder the columns in a dataframe, and keep the underlying values in the right columns.

For example this is the dataframe I have

```
cols = [ ['Three', 'Two'],['A', 'D', 'C', 'B']]
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(cols)
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,4,3,2,5,8,7,6]]*4,index=np.arange(1,5),columns=header)                  
df.loc[:,('One','E')] = 9
df.loc[:,('One','F')] = 10

>>> df
```

And I would like to change it as follows:

```
header2 = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['One', 'Two', 'Three'], ['E', 'F', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]*4,index=np.arange(1,5), columns=header2)
>>>>df2
```

Comment: seperate question - which syntax do I use in order for the dataframe to show up here

Comment: Your MultiIndex in the first and second DataFrames aren't the same... what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Basically I am trying to re-order the columns, change the top headers to 'One', 'Two', Three' and for the 'Two' and 'Three' headers, re-order the bottom headers to 'A','B','C','D'

Comment: Can you explain why the final ordering is  "One Two Three" and not "One Three Two"?

Comment: This is just an example, the point is that I am looking for a way to put the columns to be in any particular order (not necessarily alphabetical)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, define a categorical ordering on the top level. Then, call `sort_index` on the first axis with both levels.

```
v = pd.Categorical(df.columns.get_level_values(0), 
                   categories=['One', 'Two', 'Three'], 
                   ordered=True)
v2 = pd.Categorical(df.columns.get_level_values(1), 
                    categories=['E', 'F', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'D'],
                    ordered=True)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([v, v2]) 

df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=[0, 1])
```

```
df
  One     Two          Three         
    E   F   C  B  A  D     C  B  A  D
1   9  10   7  6  5  8     3  2  1  4
2   9  10   7  6  5  8     3  2  1  4
3   9  10   7  6  5  8     3  2  1  4
4   9  10   7  6  5  8     3  2  1  4
```

Comment: Thank you, but the top headers are now not in the right order (One, Three, Two), I presume it works on the bottom headers because in this example the required order is in alphabetical order, but I am looking for a solution where I can do this in any required order

Comment: @Jelmerd It is ordered Lexicographically. I've edited my answer with what you want. You can do the same thing with the second level.

Comment: Thank you, although it is still not quite clear how I would sort the bottom level, let's say for example that I would like the bottom level to be E F C B A D C B A D, can I pass a list with this order for the bottom level?

Comment: @Jelmerd No problem, you can also upvote the answer if it was helpful. Thanks!